# how to know the webpage is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a iframe and i am redirecting pages in iframe. 
how to get the event for each page loading finish.

main.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://www.child.html" id="childframe" style="height:100px"></iframe>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(window).load(function(){ 
        var Body = $("#childframe").contents().find("body");
        var Element = Body.find("tag");
        // page is redirecting to new page
        $(Element[0].click());

        window.setTimeout(reallyNext, 1000);
        function reallyNext() {
            //how to know inner page is loaded  
            var result= Body.find("#tag1");
            //how to get element from anotherpage.html

            $(result).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(event) {                  
                //how to reach here
            }); 
        }    
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

child.html

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
    <p><a href="../anotherpage.html"></a><br></p>
</body>
</html>
```

please tell me how to know the inner page of iframe has done loading?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onload paremeter inside the body tag, which runs after the page is loaded.
For example:

```
<body onload="myJavascriptFunction();" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#childframe').ready(function() {
    ...
});
```

or

```
$('#childframe').load(function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">
    iframe = document.getElementById("frameid");

    WaitForIFrame();

    function WaitForIFrame() {
        if (iframe.readyState != "complete") {
            setTimeout("WaitForIFrame();", 200);
        } else {
            done();
        }
    }

    function done() {
        //some code after iframe has been loaded
    }
</script>
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

You can hook on the `onLoad` javascript event of the `<iframe />` element (like `<iframe onLoad="myHandler" />`, where myHandler is your js function), or, if using jQuery, with the following snippet:

```
$('#childframe').load(function() {
   // your code handling the iframe loaded. 
});
```

Note, that your code needs to be part of the page that holds the `iframe` not the page within it.